# jquery .hover() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following code, I am attempting to act upon the li element being hovered over.

HTML:

```
<div id="featured">
         <ul>
              <li class="active">foo</li>
              <li class="">bar</li>
              <li class="">giraffe</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#featured ul li').hover(function(){
        //do stuff, or not
        });
    });
```

But this line of code is causing the following error in FF and I'm clueless as to what is causing it.

> g.guid is undefined

This occurs even if the line of JS has nothing occurring inside the function. 
Any insight would be welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? That sounds like an old version. Also prior to v1.4, `.hover()` takes two functions.

Comment: This is the problem, just add an empty function as the 2nd parameter (or use the event directly instead of hover).

Comment: I hadn't though of that. I'm using the version built into drupal 6 which appears (in my case) to be 1.2.6.

Comment: Yeah, then you've to pass a second function to `hover`. Or you can switch to `mouseover`.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery hover has 2 functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#featured ul li').hover(
       function(){
        //do stuff on hover over
       },
       function(){
        //do stuff on hover out
       });
});
```